# In State Duration

Tags: anylogic, statechart

How can I estimate the duration an agent stays in a specific state in a state chart?
I want to count the number of times an agent enters a state and the duration before the transition us triggered to the other state

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

1. create a variable `timerState` of type double.
2. On entry of the state: `timerState=time();`
3. On Exit of the state: `double timeInState = time()-timerState;`

Then do what you want with that `timeInState` value.

Be VERY careful with this, though. You should not use the `timerState` variable for anything else.